# Receiving SMS from SIM

Tags: sms, at-command

I'm wondering, when I try to receive sms text message from a SIM using [AT+CMGL](https://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgl-text-mode/), can a message contain `OK<CR><LF>`? if so how should I know where is the end of the message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, and as you have identified if the information text contains a final result code you loose, because there is no way to know.

This is partially covered in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) which forbids the modem to introduce false final result codes if it breaks up lines:

> Note that the DCE may insert intermediate  characters in very long
>   information text responses, in order to avoid overrunning DTE receive
>   buffers. If intermediate  characters are included, the DCE shall
>   not include the character sequences "0 " (3/0, 0/13) or "OK"
>   (4/15, 4/11, 0/13), so that DTE can avoid false detection of the end
>   of these information text responses.

And also several command (+GMI, +GMM, +GMR, +GSN, +GOI and +GCAP) are explicitly forbidden to produce text that embed the `OK` final result code (but it does not mention anything about `ERROR`...).

Similarly for [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) it forbids some commands (+CGMI, +CGMM, +CGMR, +CGSN, +CEER and +CLAC) from containing `OK` (and again no mention of `ERROR`...).

[27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) does not specify anything regarding embedded final result codes, so to avoid the issue of embedded final result codes for `AT+CMGL` you need to read the message in PDU mode, there you have a guarantee that the information text will not contain `OK`, `ERROR`, etc.

Comment: an you please answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918244/at-command-to-select-a-button